# Override a function in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Am having a plugin, In that I need to change some text it in, but this function doesn't have hook to use.

Usually the function will be override by using `remove_action()` or `remove_filter()`. For both the function we need filter name to override. But this plugin function doesn't add any filters.

Now I need to override this function.

For example

**Plugin.php in plugin**

```
function plugin(){
    echo 'hello';
    echo 'welcome you';
}
```

**Function.php in theme**

I want to the function plugin() in plugin.php to

```
function theme_plugin(){
    echo 'hello';
    echo 'You are welcome';
}
```

There is not `add_action` for `plugin()`.

How to override the `plugin()` to `theme_plugin()`?

Comment: Hi, Am talking about WordPress plugin and themes. Sorry to not mentioned there

Answer (score 2):

Look here [Redefining PHP function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640958/redefining-php-function), you can't override php function or overload it. You have to find another way for solving your problem.

Regards,

Comment: Welcome to SO! One thing that you'll want to do when providing an answer is actually show some source code (because links can easily break over time).

Comment: Yes sorry for wasting your time :) Good luck !

Comment: I wouldn't say you wasted anyone's time. :) When you have enough rep, you can flag questions as duplicates (and would be able to provide a link to the post in your answer).

Answer (score 0):

If am right, you can us this link: http://sltaylor.co.uk/blog/customizing-new-user-email-pluggable-function/

**** Edit**

I have no much experience with wordpress. But here is someone asking for the same: [Overriding a theme function from plugin in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012198/overriding-a-theme-function-from-plugin-in-wordpress)

And the marked answer is:

Unless the function is meant to be overridden, no. This is basic PHP. You can't redefine a function. If you try you will get a fatal error.

Parts of WordPress are written to be overwritten. Look at /wp-includes/pluggable.php. Every function in there is wrapped in a if( !function_exists(...) ) conditional. Unless your theme did the same, and some do for some functions, you can't overwrite.

Look around for filters that might help you instead.

Looking at your code, you should be able to unhook that. Just make sure to hook the unhook late enough. That is not a good solution, though since you are breaking theme functionality and also must know the know the names of all the hooked functions that themes are using.

Is there something in $fragments, or in $_POST or $_GET or anything else, that you can use to conditionally run your code, leaving the rest alone.

Anyway, Wordpress is opensource, so you can change the code by yourself? Why just change the plugin?